# How to optimize an api performance

Tags: php, api, curl

I am using a script that fetch users infos from an api.
This is how it works I get the id of the user posted in php.
Then make a curl request to the api with the user id to get his infos.
The problem is that whenever the user refresh the page my script do the work again and fetch the infos to display them. But this api take much time to respond and it makes my script works slower.
Is there any solution to cache the api response for sometime (The server i request force cache : no cache in headers) ?
I am thinking about creating a directory with json file (the api response) for every user id . Or I can go with mysql solution .
What's the best solution for me ?
N.B : Im getting about 200 000 request/day.
Thanks

Comment: Use redis for caching api response.

Comment: Give more details if you are using some framework or composer to allow us elaborate an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually need to optimize this API, so that updates will be there as you expect them to be.

However, if you insist that caching is appropriate for your use, there's no need to reinvent the wheel.  Simply put Nginx, Varnish, etc. in front of the API server.  Then configure your application to request from this caching proxy rather than the API server directly.

See also:

- [Nginx Caching Configuration Documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/)

Comment: My script make these api call to instagram server and in the response I get a cache:no cache header.

Comment: @YassineDevlopper You can override it in your proxy server config.

Comment: Will this work for such a huge number of queries ? Will it impact the performance of my server ?

Comment: I am thinking about another solution : Create a directory with api.php file make requests to this file instead of the same page and let cloudflare cache the results

Comment: @YassineDevlopper Why Cloudflare?  You're going to get less control that way...

Comment: I tried to use page rule to set cache = everything in the directory /api in mywebsite set it to 10 minutes(average session in my website). So users see my page => my page send requests to /api/api.php?id=XXXX the first time i get the response then the content of this page is cached for 10mins in cloudflare servers.